# Double.isFinite implementation detail - why DoubleConsts.MAX_VALUE rather than Double.MAX_VALUE?

Tags: java, java-8

I looked up the implementation of [`Double.isFinite()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#isFinite-double-) which exists since java 8 (because I needed the functionality in java 7):

```
public static boolean isFinite(double d) {
    return Math.abs(d) <= DoubleConsts.MAX_VALUE;
}
```

where `DoubleConsts.MAX_VALUE` is `double sun.misc.DoubleConsts.MAX_VALUE` with the value `1.7976931348623157E308`. This seems to be equivalent to `Double.MAX_VALUE`, which is defined as:

```
public static final double MAX_VALUE = 0x1.fffffffffffffP+1023; // 1.7976931348623157e+308
```

Why does this implementation use the constant from the `sun.misc`-package instead of [`Double.MAX_VALUE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#MAX_VALUE)?

([`Float.isFinite`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#isFinite-float-) uses the same pattern)

Comment: good question, I would understand if that would have defined as `public static final double MAX_VALUE = DoubleConsts.MAX_VALUE`; so that constants would all be in a single place, but this...

Comment: Interestingly, [this link](https://alvinalexander.com/java/jwarehouse/openjdk-8/jdk/src/share/classes/sun/misc/DoubleConsts.java.shtml) shows that `DoubleConsts.MAX_VALUE` is defined directly as `java.lang.Double.MAX_VALUE`. Maybe whoever wrote that function just googled something and found the `DoubleConsts.MAX_VALUE` reference first?

Comment: The case of `MIN_NORMAL` is even stranger to me - `Double` and `DoubleConsts` contain *different*  literal representations for this value.

Comment: Actually, there is only one place where `Double` directly uses it's own constants without the indirection through `DoubleConsts`: `isInfinite` uses `POSITIVE_INFINITY` and `NEGATIVE_INFINITY` directly, although there is also `DoubleConsts.POSITIVE_INFINITY` and  `DoubleConsts.NEGATIVE_INFINITY`.

Comment: Speculation: the [ticket that led to this method's addition](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-7092404) mentions that it was previously contained in the `sun.misc.FpUtils` maybe they just left the code unchanged an merely moved it?

Comment: @Hulk I've seen this one too.. but I *hoped* it would be more then simply moving it...

Comment: @Eugene so did I... I added an answer documenting what I found, but perhaps someone can come up with a better reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason seems to be mostly a historic one:

The funtionality provided by these methods was previously located in `sun.misc.FpUtils`. This class does not directly depend on `Double`, it only imports

```
import sun.misc.FloatConsts;
import sun.misc.DoubleConsts;
```

so the implementation made more sense there - it seems that it was exactly the same:

```
public static boolean isFinite(double d) {
    return Math.abs(d) <= DoubleConsts.MAX_VALUE;
}
```

See also [The ticket that led to moving this to `Double`](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-7092404)

Comment: if so, this probably would need to be reported - minor bug fix i guess